# Не отправляется post запрос через ajax с формы, пока не перезагружу страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть форма, с которой через form_input.val() забираю значения и отправляю их post запросом на сервер. Как только открываю страницу, заполняю форму и пытаюсь отправить получают ответ что поля не могут быть пустыми, получается что jquery не получает никаких значений с формы. Как только перезагружаю страницу (форма при этом остается заполненной) - сразу отправляется.
Значения получаю так:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var switch_name = $('#switch_name');
var switch_ip_address = $('#switch_ip_address');
var switch_vlan = $('#switch_vlan');
var switch_start_ip = $('#switch_start_ip');
var switch_end_ip = $('#switch_end_ip');
var switch_count_ports = $('#switch_count_ports')

var arr = {
    name: String(switch_name.val()),
    ip_address: String(switch_ip_address.val()),
    vlan: Number(switch_vlan.val()),
    start_ip: Number(switch_start_ip.val()),
    end_ip: Number(switch_end_ip.val()),
    count_ports: Number(switch_count_ports.val()),
    ports: addManyPorts()
}

$('#post-button').click(function (e) {
    addSwitch();
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

В функции addSwitch собственно сам post запрос, думаю показывать его смысла нет.

Comment: Чтобы вернуть ajax запрос нужен колбэк или промис.

Comment: А через таймаут не получится?

Comment: Ну вы же не знаете сколько будет длится запрос 1сек или 10 мин

Comment: А что вкратце должно быть в коллбэке? Что то не могу сам дойти. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: тут досканально описано https://incode.pro/jquery/odna-funktsija-dlja-ajaxzaprosov-kak-vernut-dannye.html

Answer (score 0):

у Вас значения полей заполняются на событии "document.ready" а должны при событии "click" переместите:

```
var arr = {
    name: String(switch_name.val()),
    ip_address: String(switch_ip_address.val()),
    vlan: Number(switch_vlan.val()),
    start_ip: Number(switch_start_ip.val()),
    end_ip: Number(switch_end_ip.val()),
    count_ports: Number(switch_count_ports.val()),
    ports: addManyPorts()
 }
```

в:

```
$('#post-button').click(function (e) {
                       <== cюда
    addSwitch();
    e.preventDefault()
})
```